# SQLLoader Strange Behavior

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I am using sqlloader to import pdf files to the database as blobs. The control file is as follows

```
LOAD DATA
INFILE *
INTO TABLE pdf_files
APPEND
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(
    pdfid   char(20),
    pdf_year     char(4),
    pdf_province    char(2),
    pdf_load_location       char(100),
    pdf_file        lobfile (pdf_load_location) TERMINATED BY EOF
)
BEGINDATA   
test-form-en,2012,QC,/home/oracle/TestForms/forms/en/test-form.pdf,
```

Then I got error messages in the log:

```
Record 1: Rejected - Error on table PDF_FILES.
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SCOTT.SYS_C0011439) violated
```

I checked the constraint SCOTT.SYS_C0011439 as follows

```
select * from user_constraints where constraint_name='SYS_C0011439';
```

Then I found constraint SYS_C0011439 is actually on an irrelevant table 'T2032'. This table has nothing to do with table pdf_files which I want to import data. And the constraint is the not null check constraint.

Anybody knows why sqlloader gets some irrelevant table/constraint checked when I tried to load data to just one specific table? Thanks

Comment: This might be because of a foreign key

Can you please provide the complete output of :

select * from user_constraints where constraint_name='SYS_C0011439';

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem again and this time found the reason. There is already an data entry (blob with the specified pdf location) in the database for the rejected record.